# Selection Sort Python with no built ins

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, selection

I know python has a bunch of built in functions but I tried coding selection sort minimizing  built ins because i'm trying to understand the algorithm.  My output is not correct for my  selection sort.  Any help appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

```
def selection_sort(list):
    for index in range(0, len(list)):
        for i in range(index,len(list)):
            iSmall = index

            if list[iSmall] > list[i]:
                iSmall = i
        list[index], list[iSmall] = list[iSmall], list[index]
    return list  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print selection_sort([5,2,4,6,1,3,])
```

Comment: `range` is a built-in. :)

Comment: It is bad form to name variables with the name of a built-in type.

Comment: @ the people downvoting -- why? It seems like a decent question to me, and it's not asking for code, just debugging help.

Comment: @Michael0x2a is asking for code bad? I thought asking for code (or anything else for that matter) was only bad when you haven't done anything.

Comment: @angelatlarge -- sorry, that's what I meant. Asking for code without showing any effort is bad, like you said, but this question doesn't appear to be doing that, nor do I see any other major problem with it, so I was confused as to why this question had downvotes.

Comment: I guess it was considered a type of non-helpful [syntax error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed/123742#123742) question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iSmall = index` is out of place.  I am not mentioning anything that all the commenters mentioned, which is all true (as of this edit).  So, your code with `iSmall = index` in the right place:

```
def selection_sort(list):
    for index in range(0, len(list)):
        iSmall = index
        for i in range(index,len(list)):
            if list[iSmall] > list[i]:
                iSmall = i
        list[index], list[iSmall] = list[iSmall], list[index]
    return list  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print selection_sort([5,2,4,6,1,3,])
```

In other words, you are looking for the index to the smallest number (and trying to store it in `iSMall`, but you are resetting `iSmall` to `index` at every iteration of the loop `for i in range(index,len(list)):`. So `iSmall` does not get set correctly, it is always set to `index`, unless in the last iteration of the inner loop it is changed to something else.